# TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not iterable

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of probabilities:

```
proba =  :[[0.254 0.556 0.025] [0.898 0567 .112]]
```

want max value from each as `[[0.556] [0.898]]`

How i can do it?
Tried 2 methods:

```
 1. max(sublist) for sublist in proba 
 2. proba = map(max,proba)
```

and getting error `"TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not iterable"`

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's with the `:` before your array?

Comment: The code you provided is not even valid Python

Comment: Please check the syntax before posting

Answer (score 1):

I can notice some problems in your code, 
first of all, your data list is not in the correct format,
commas are missing and there is an extra ':' at the right of the equal sign

```
proba = [[0.254, 0.556, 0.025], [0.898, 0.567, .112]]
```

And then you can get the answer like this :

```
max_ = [max(i) for i in proba]
```